# Webpack 2: WARNING in .png, .svg, .. DEPRECATED. Configure optipng's optimizationLevel option in it's own options. (optipng.optimizationLevel)

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

This WARNING is printed ~20 times when running `webpack` - it processes and bundles just fine, but what does it mean? How do I get rid of it?

Googling around provides little to no help unfortunately.

Here's my webpack config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        dashboard: './js/main.js',
        vendor: ["fixed-data-table","react","react-dom","jquery", "bootstrap", "vis",],
    },
    output: { path: "../public", filename: 'bundle.js' },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "static/vendor.bundle.js"}),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("/static/[name].css"),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'es2015', 'react', 'stage-0',
                    ],

            }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader'}),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=~/.local/share/Trash/[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false', {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    }
                ],

            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=~/.local/share/Trash/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Sample of WARNINGS(there are many!)

```
WARNING in ./~/vis/dist/img/network/addNodeIcon.png
DEPRECATED. Configure gifsicle's interlaced option in it's own options. (gifsicle.interlaced)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/vis/dist/vis.min.css 6:12847-12887
 @ ./~/vis/dist/vis.min.css

WARNING in ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
DEPRECATED. Configure gifsicle's interlaced option in it's own options. (gifsicle.interlaced)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 6:3700-3752
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass query string parameter, in webpack2 there is a **query** section for that.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Query section? I've been trying to find webpack 2 example configs, but without luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You now need to specify your options to the specific optimizer.  so a previous webpack 1.x loader config like;

```
loaders: [
  'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]',
  'image-webpack-loader?progressive=true&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=true'
]
```

becomes

```
      use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        query: {
          name:'assets/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        query: {
          mozjpeg: {
            progressive: true,
          },
          gifsicle: {
            interlaced: true,
          },
          optipng: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
          }
        }
      }
    }]
```

Note the options object, with the query embedded inside it.

See
https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/
and 
deltones comments in this issue;
https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/68#issuecomment-275848595

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Just so you know, the `options` object is not actually needed. You can just go straight to `query`. Likewise, the `mozjpeg`, `gifsicle`, and `optipng` aren't needed, either. I'll post an answer with example.

Comment: @TetraDev that did not work for me. Needed to nest a `query` inside an `options` to make the warning go away

Comment: @galarant check my answer below. Not sure why it didnt work for you, but my answer I posted is working for me using `webpack 2.5.1`

Answer (score 10):

None of the above was working for me, taking inspiration from the official webpack2 configuration example https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/blob/master/test/webpack2.config.js this is what worked for me

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          // path where the images will be saved
          name: 'assets/img/[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        options: {
          mozjpeg: {
            quality: 65
          },
          pngquant:{
            quality: "10-20",
            speed: 4
          },
          svgo:{
            plugins: [
              {
                removeViewBox: false
              },
              {
                removeEmptyAttrs: false
              }
            ]
          },
          gifsicle: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            interlaced: false
          },
          optipng: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            interlaced: false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Webpack 2 now supports "query object" syntax, meaning you can make a separete object for the query parameters. Here is how the `image-webpack-loader` recommends it in [their documentation](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader). I updated it with the newest webpack 2 naming standards:

```
rules: [ // rules is formerly "loaders" in webpack 1
  {
    test: /\.(svg|jpe?g|png|gif|ico)(\?{0}(?=\?|$))/,
    use: [ // use is formerly "loaders" in webpack 1

      // file-loader has a bug where it doesn't yet recognize query object
      // syntax for webpack 2, so the query options `assets/images/[name].[ext]`
      // are ignored until they fix that,    
      // {
      //  loader: 'file',
      //  query: {
      //    name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]'
      //   }   
      //},

      'file?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]', // or just 'file-loader'
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack',
        query: {
          progressive: true,
          optimizationLevel: 7,
          interlaced: false,
          pngquant: {
            quality: '65-90',
            speed: 4
          }
        }

       // you can also do it like this:
       // query: {
       //    mozjpeg: {
       //       progressive: true,
       //    },
       //    gifsicle: {
       //       interlaced: false,
       //    },
       //    optipng: {
       //       optimizationLevel: 7,
       //    }
       // }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that `rules` is the same as webpack 1 top level `loaders`, and `use` is the same as webpack 1 `loaders` at the individual loader level (the one after `test`). As you can see, it was confusing before, which is why the schema has been renamed in webpack 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by having params in the query object that now belong in one of the child objects.

for example:

This is bad:

```
 'file-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    query: {
                        progressive: true,
                        optimizationLevel: 7,
                        pngquant: {
                            quality: '65-90',
                            speed: 4
                        },
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true
                        },
                        gifsicle: {
                            interlaced: true
                        },
                        optipng: {
                            optimizationLevel: 7
                        }
                    }
                }
```

where this is good:

```
                'file-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    query: {
                        pngquant: {
                            quality: '65-90',
                            speed: 4
                        },
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true
                        },
                        gifsicle: {
                            interlaced: true
                        },
                        optipng: {
                            optimizationLevel: 7
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following webpack2 config of image-webpack-loader works fine for me:

```
{
    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
    options: {
        progressive: true,
        optipng: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
        },
        mozjpeg: {
            quality: 65
        },
        gifsicle: {
            interlaced: true,
        },
        pngquant: {
            quality: '65-90',
            speed: 4
        }
    }
}
```