# webpack error warning in png svg deprecated

Tags: webpack

I have a very strange error. I got this exact same here mentioned here

[Webpack 2: WARNING in .png, .svg, .. DEPRECATED. Configure optipng's optimizationLevel option in it's own options. (optipng.optimizationLevel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206190/webpack-2-warning-in-png-svg-deprecated-configure-optipngs-optimizatio)

Ii impleted the solution and now my webpack looks like this

https://codepaste.net/8owse4

But now i get this error

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:60
    throw new Error("Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders'");
    ^
```

Error: Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders'

So, I am in kind of loop. I am using webpack 2. I understand I have to reconfigure webpack . But, its kind of loop. Its just not working. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doodlebot said above, [webpack2 now uses](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules) `module.rules` instead of `module.loaders` but `module.loaders` still works according to the documentation:

> The old loader configuration was superseded by a more powerful rules system, which allows configuration of loaders and more. For compatibility reasons, the old module.loaders syntax is still valid and the old names are parsed. The new naming conventions are easier to understand and are a good reason to upgrade the configuration to using module.rules.

So it's not the problem here. If you choose to use `module.loaders`, you need to pass an array of objects to it and each of those objects must have a field `loader` as your error points out:

> Error: Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders'

This is what you have currently:

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');



module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    //loaders
    module: {
        loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['stage-0','react','es2015'],
        plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties"]
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ],  
  },
  {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            
            {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        query: {
          name:'assets/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        query: {
          mozjpeg: {
            progressive: true,
          },
          gifsicle: {
            interlaced: true,
          },
          optipng: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  },

  
]
    }
};
```

And from that you had spelled the `loader` field for your css as `loaders`

```
loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
```

That should be

```
loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
```

I also noticed you are mixing syntax. If you use `module.loaders` then your objects should have `test` and `loader`, if you use `module.rules` then your objects have `test` and `use`. Don't mix them. Here are examples:

```
module{ loaders: [{test: /\.css$/, loader: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}] }

module{ rules: [{test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}] }
```

Your `use` or `loader` field can take a string (`style-loader!css-loader`) or array (`[ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]`) but that shouldn't make you pluralize the field name

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the migration guide for Webpack 2 I think that error is coming from `module.loaders` needing to be `module.rules`.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

I took a pass at migrating your config file.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    //loaders
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['stage-0', 'react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: true
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 7
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```