# Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list, webpack error

Tags: webpack

I am getting this error

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:54
            if(!element.loader || element.loader.indexOf("!") >= 0) throw new Error("Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list");
                                                                    ^

Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list
at getLoadersFromObject (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:54:65)
at LoadersList.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:78:12)
```

I was getting deprecated warning

[Webpack 2: WARNING in .png, .svg, .. DEPRECATED. Configure optipng's optimizationLevel option in it's own options. (optipng.optimizationLevel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206190/webpack-2-warning-in-png-svg-deprecated-configure-optipngs-optimizatio)

after following above thread. I introduced option property in my webpack. Here's my webpack config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: { app: './src/app.js' },
  output: {
    filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['stage-0', 'react', 'es2015'],
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ],

        options: {
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: true
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But I am still getting that error.

Edit 1 - after Michael's answer

I still got error, this is my webpack now

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: {app: './src/app.js' },
  output: {filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: 'babel-loader',query: {
        presets: ['stage-0','react','es2015'],
        plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties"]
    } },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'  },
      {
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[sha512:hash:hex].[ext]'
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        bypassOnDebug: true,
        mozjpeg: {
          progressive: true
        },
        gifsicle: {
          interlaced: true
        },
        optipng: {
          optimizationLevel: 7
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
    ]
  }
}
```

the error looks like this now

```
    ERROR in ./public/imgs/common/jcrop/Jcrop.gif
Module parse failed: /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js!/home/ubuntu/workspace/public/imgs/common/jcrop/Jcrop.gif Unexpected character ' (1:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character ' (1:6)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2413:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2191:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1774:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:292:15
    at context.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:148:14)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js:71:9
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/main-blessed3.css?z=1490800022920 6:271558-271606
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your last rule:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  loaders: [
    'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
    'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
  ],

  options: {
    query: {
      mozjpeg: {
        progressive: true
      },
      gifsicle: {
        interlaced: true
      },
      optipng: {
        optimizationLevel: 7
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You define options on the rule, but you have multiple loaders. This is not allowed, it only works if it's a single loader (as a shortcut), otherwise you need to specify the options on the loader directly not the rule. The loaders don't even work in webpack 2 because you're leaving off the `-loader` suffix which is no longer allowed in webpack 2 (as shown in the [Automatic `-loader` module name extension removed](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed)).

Also don't use inline query options, use [`options`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#useentry) on the loader (`query` exists for compatibility reasons and `options` should be preferred). Because of the inline configuration you get the deprecation warnings, as you still have the options set there. Also your `file-loader` options are not correct, the type of the hash is specified in the `name` option with `[<hashType>:hash:<digestType>:<length>]` as described in [Filename template placeholders](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#filename-template-placeholders).

The correct and clean version of the above rule is:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[sha512:hash:hex].[ext]'
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        bypassOnDebug: true,
        mozjpeg: {
          progressive: true
        },
        gifsicle: {
          interlaced: true
        },
        optipng: {
          optimizationLevel: 7
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

By the way, you also have `.svg` specified in another rule (for your fonts), this will likely have unwanted effects, you should only have one rule that matches it.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I applied your solution but I am still getting error. can you please check original post.

Comment: can you please take a look the error ?You are my last hope :)

Comment: Looks like it's trying to apply only `image-webpack-loader` (without the `file-loader`). Make sure not to specify any loaders inline where you import `Jcrop.gif`. Can't really tell more from the error.